# No error description in text property of IOErrorEvent, only error number

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am using in my application a swfLoader and I am listening IOErrorEvent, something like this:

```
<mx:SWFLoader id="Load" ioError="IOErrorHandler(event)"/>
```

then I am catching some IO errors and show them as a text in some label:

```
private function IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
        label.text = event.text;
    }
}
```

The problem is next: when I run this app on my enviroment, everything is OK. During loading non-existence swf-file I have the next error in label: **"Error #2036: load never completed"** - and this is the expected behaviour.

But then I run this app on some enviroment without Flash Builder, label text is next: **"Error #2036"**
And that is all, no description.
Does anybody know why this happens? Maybe I should build my project with some special keys?

Comment: This is just the difference in behavior in the flash debug player vs. regular.   It's normal and I'm pretty sure there is no way to get error descriptions in the regular flash player.  You can however store friendly error messages and match them to the error number manually - might be manageable if you're just talking about a small handful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a difference between the DEBUG version of flash player, and the regular version of flash player.

Likely the reason is to save space on the flash player install (which long ago making flash player as small and quick to install as possible was key) - though I'm guessing as to the why.

You will need to display your own friendly messages if you wish to show that to the end users:

```
private function IOErrorHandler(event:IOErrorEvent):void {
    switch(event.errorID){
        case 2036:
            label.text = "Load Never Completed";
            break;
    }
}
```

If you want a list of errors you can parse pragmatically, someone has made a handy xml file here:

http://divillysausages.com/files/runtimeErrors.xml